# Anchor link not going to correct section of page

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So I have a page with various sections, that in my case are divs with unique ids. In that same page I use these type of anchors and it works like a charm.

```
<a href="#sobre" className="nav-item nav-link">Sobre</a>
<a href="#projetos" className="nav-item nav-link">Projetos</a>
<a href="#reunioes" className="nav-item nav-link">Reuniões</a>
<a href="#workshops_palestras" className="nav-item nav-link">Workshops/Palestras</a>
<a href="#contactos" className="nav-item nav-link">Contactos</a>
```

How ever, in another page, I use these kinds of anchors.

```
<a href="/rcviseu#sobre" className="nav-item nav-link">Sobre</a>
<a href="/rcviseu#projetos" className="nav-item nav-link">Projetos</a>
<a href="/rcviseu#reunioes" className="nav-item nav-link">Reuniões</a>
<a href="/rcviseu#workshops_palestras" className="nav-item nav-link">Workshops/Palestras</a>
<a href="/rcviseu#contactos" className="nav-item nav-link">Contactos</a>
```

So, in this last page, if I click any of the anchors, sometimes it goes to the right place, and other times it just gives up scrolling in some place in the middle of the page.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: My *guess* is that it's performing the anchor navigation while React is still loading content and modifying the DOM.  So the navigation "works" but almost immediately the page content changes and pushes the intended section further down.  There may be `react-router` packages to help with this.  Or you might monitor the URL values in a `useEffect` call and scroll the page manually in that effect.

Comment: You don't need the /rcviseu part of the address. Same page links start with #.